# Border tr that include th and table section

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I am writing my final project at PHP and JS. I need help with the html and CSS styling.

This is my sign form, I want help in 2 things.

1. I want to do that the whole row (tr) that include th while be with border, now I know to do it only that every th have border.
2. I want to divide the table to sections and to style every section in other CSS code.

How can I do it?

This my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <table id="t">
            <tr>
                <th>Basic info</th>
                <th>Contact info</th>
                <th>About me</th>


            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input placeholder="First name"></td>
                <td><input placeholder="Phone"></td>
                <td rowspan="3"><textarea rows="8" placeholder="About me"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input placeholder="Last name"></td>
                <td><input placeholder="Area"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input placeholder="Degree"></td>
                <td><input placeholder="Email"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><th colspan="2">Social networks</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input row placeholder="Facebook link"></td>
                <td><input row placeholder="Website link"></td>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td><input row placeholder="Twitter link"></td>
                <td><input row placeholder="Medium link"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input row placeholder="Instagram link"></td>
                <td><input row placeholder="Google link"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit">שלח</button></td></tr>

        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
table{
    margin: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
td{
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#t textarea{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
tr>th{
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For (1), tr's can only have borders when the table is `border-collapse:collapse`.
For (2), you can put rows in `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` sections and style those separately.

Maybe you can have multiple `<tbody`> sections and use nth-of-type to select them but I don't know.

Differences in the below

- addition of thead, tbody, tfoot in the html
- style tbody as an example
- border-collapse:collapse on the table style
- tr style on the first tr

```css
table {
  margin: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#t textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

tbody {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table id="t">
    <thead>
      <tr style="border:solid 1px">
        <th>Basic info</th>
        <th>Contact info</th>
        <th>About me</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="First name">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Phone">
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3">
          <textarea rows="8" placeholder="About me"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Last name">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Area">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Degree">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Social networks</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input row placeholder="Facebook link">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input row placeholder="Website link">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input row placeholder="Twitter link">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input row placeholder="Medium link">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input row placeholder="Instagram link">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input row placeholder="Google link">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <button type="submit">שלח</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>
</form>
```